# How to manipulate json string before being emitted from web method?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a web method like below. MyClass is defined in a proxy class because it's coming from another external web service.

```
[WebMethod]
     [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
     public MyClass GetCustomer() 
     {
       MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
       (populate myClass from another web service)

       return myClass;
     }
```

However I don't want all the properties in MyClass to be returned to the browser. How do I exclude some properties? I am trying to minimize the json payload and have it only include the data the browser needs. I don't want to define another minimalist class and copy stuff from MyClass to it.

Answer (score 2):

Just decorate with ScriptIgnoreAttribute whatever property you don't want serialized with it.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public class Group
{
    // The JavaScriptSerializer ignores this field.
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public string Comment;

    // The JavaScriptSerializer serializes this field. 
    public string GroupName;
}
```

You can try [ScriptIgnoreAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.WEB.MVC.CONTROLLER.JSON%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true)

hope it helps

Edited -

You can do something like this

```
[WebMethod]

public MyClass GetCustomer() {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass() { key = "value", ... };
    return new filteredClass() {filterKey = myClass.value};
}
```

Comment: The class is defined in a proxy file, reference.cs. I can't add the attribute there. I am looking for a solution at the webmethod level.

Comment: What is key , filteredClass, ..? What if myClass has tens of pproperties? As I said, I prefer not to define a new class. Isn't there a way to manipulate the json or is this a blackbox?

Comment: I don't think you can do without new class.